# Uniquely identify a common html input per file upload request

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file-upload, blueimp

My front end is using blueimps file-upload jquery plugin.

I have a file upload form where you can select multiple files. This form has common input fields shared amongst all files. The framework handles posting each file individually with the common inputs.

I now have a requirement where i have an input that is specific per file as part of the form. How can i dynamically post the correct input per file upload?

Scenario:

I have a duplicated input type named "comment". (Comment per file)
This input exists per file. By default as the input is the same name per file, it binds on the server side to my model object as a delimited string. I could bind to increments of this field (for example comment1, comment2, comment3) but this is not a clean solution.

On the client side how do i post the correct file related comment input?

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For anyone that uses the basic plugin and needed the above requirement, here it is.

For every file I add, I dynamically add a table row with file specific inputs.

Before my changes, the plugin posted the form with all inputs. The file specific inputs had the same name and received as a string array on the server side.

What i did to change this was on the callback add(), i assign the context to that new unique table row.
Then on submit, I find all file specific inputs from the context and all the common form inputs by a unique id.

I then serialise both and merge them together before assigning back to formData.

Example:

Common inputs in the form:

```
<table id="commonFields" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <form:label   path="firstName">
                        <spring:message code="fileupload.upload.member.input.firstname.label"/>
                        <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" />
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="firstName"  size="30"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <form:label   path="lastName">
                        <spring:message code="fileupload.upload.member.input.lastname.label"/> 
                        <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="lastName"  size="30"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Javascript snippet

```
$('#fileuploadForm').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
      add: function (e, data) {
          $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                var rowCount = $('#fileUploadTable tr').length;
                $('#fileUploadTable tr:last').after('<tr id=' +   rowCount + ' ><td>' + file.name + '</td><td><span class="field"></span></td><td><input type="text" size="30" value=""  name=comment></td><td>' + file.size + '</td>  <td>Ready to upload</td></tr>');
                data.context = $('#' + rowCount + '');
          });
        $("#upload").click(function () {
                data.submit();
            });
    },
    submit: function (e, data) {
        //this will overwrite all the form data posted to the server
        //may need to find all inputs and selects too
        var fileSpecificFields = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();

        var commonFieldInputs = $('#commonFields').find(':input').serializeArray();
        data.formData = $.merge(commonFieldInputs, fileSpecificFields);
    }
});
```

Cheers,
Shane. :

Comment: The documentation explain how to do it in an even easier way https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data#setting-formdata-on-upload-start-for-each-individual-file-upload (maybe it didn't exist when u posted ur question)

Comment: I believe that example is for the ui version plugin and template engine; NOT the basic plugin.

Comment: Indeed it seems that this is the case